# How to automatically download a spreadsheet generated by a website?

Tags: python, excel, vba

Please bear with me, I'm an extreme novice when it comes to this kind of stuff. I am trying create an reoccurring automatic download of an excel spreadsheet that is generated from a website. I have no idea how to do it or with what means.

The website is: https://transparentdata.idaho.gov/data/#/29262

This has a link on it ("Download" in upper right corner) that generates an excel file of all state employees and their pay rates. I would like to make it where it automatically downloads this spreadsheet once a week so that I may compare data over time. Can anyone explain how automate this download?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check out posts on here for things like download and webscraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Firefox, I opened the web developers tools > Network, and I noticed that when you click on Download > Export current view > Confirm, it fires a POST request, which returns you a job id that you can poll for your results:

With cURL from the cmdline (the POST is implicit with `--data-raw`):

```
$ curl 'https://transparentdata.idaho.gov/api/transactions/v2/export/df44b6b3-0697-4764-88b4-8de532ef5748' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"report_id":29262,"query_params":{},"amount_column_state":{"total":141323290.18,"column_name":"Pay Rate ($)"}}'
{"job_id":"7d3dc5b8-dbbb-44ba-8eac-7a3ed8f9d226"}
```

Then you can use that id to continue polling with GET requests until the "state" is in running and not in "finished":

```
$ curl 'https://transparentdata.idaho.gov/api/v2/async_jobs/7d3dc5b8-dbbb-44ba-8eac-7a3ed8f9d226' |jq
{
  "id": "7d3dc5b8-dbbb-44ba-8eac-7a3ed8f9d226",
  "state": "running",
  "job_type": "GridDataApi::Dataset::Export::ExportUrl",
  "timestamps": {
    "created_at": "2021-02-26T11:44:58.852-08:00",
    "started_at": "2021-02-26T11:44:58.883-08:00"
  }
}
```

Then the payload would change to:

```
$ curl 'https://transparentdata.idaho.gov/api/v2/async_jobs/7d3dc5b8-dbbb-44ba-8eac-7a3ed8f9d226' |jq
{
  "id": "7d3dc5b8-dbbb-44ba-8eac-7a3ed8f9d226",
  "state": "finished",
  "job_type": "GridDataApi::Dataset::Export::ExportUrl",
  "timestamps": {
    "created_at": "2021-02-26T11:44:58.852-08:00",
    "started_at": "2021-02-26T11:44:58.883-08:00",
    "finished_at": "2021-02-26T11:45:08.255-08:00"
  },
  "job_result": {
    "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/og-datamanager-uploads/production/grid_data_api/dataset_filtered_exports/d9d94de7-d9d4-4dde-927e-81d8facaeecd/csvs/original/dataset_filtered_export_scratch20210226-127461-7hofsf.csv?1614369247"
  }
}
```

Finally, you can use that url in "job_result" > "url" to download the csv you're looking for.

Converting this into Python should be fairly easy with [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/), and there are thousands of guides and posts also here in SO about that.

To schedule this to run weekly you may use crontab or other similar tools depending on your OS.

---

Here's the python version; requires `requests` (`pip install requests`):

```py
>>> import requests
>>> import time
>>> 
>>> export_url = 'https://transparentdata.idaho.gov/api/transactions/v2/export/df44b6b3-0697-4764-88b4-8de532ef5748'
>>> export_json = {"report_id": 29262, "query_params": {}, "amount_column_state": {"total": 141323290.18, "column_name": "Pay Rate ($)"}}
>>> polling_base_url = 'https://transparentdata.idaho.gov/api/v2/async_jobs/'
>>> 
>>> def extract_url():
...   export_req = requests.post(export_url, json=export_json)
...   polling_id = export_req.json()['job_id']
...   query_state = None
...   while query_state != "finished":
...     time.sleep(5)
...     result_req = requests.get(polling_base_url + polling_id)
...     query_state = result_req.json()['state']
...   return result_req.json()['job_result']['url']
... 
>>> extract_url()
'https://s3.amazonaws.com/og-datamanager-uploads/production/grid_data_api/dataset_filtered_exports/479af43d-b28d-4fad-b885-41cf74998039/csvs/original/dataset_filtered_export_scratch20210301-7-1uex46m.csv?1614573842'
```

Comment: Thanks Alberto. I appreciate you taking the time to respond! Your break down is very helpful and I'll keep tinkering with it!

Comment: Glad it helped! Mark the answer with the green tick if it solved your problem

Comment: Alberto, I noticed that the job result URL only points to the specific day it was generated. How would one go about executing a single item that generates an up-to-date version? I also don't know how to just make this happen through coding. I just went to the URL haha

Comment: @burntheboats I've edited my answer and added the python version. If this helped you mark the answer using the tick on the left.

Comment: Sorry I'm such a noob. I pasted this into PyCharm and it seems to run except it doesn't seem to do anything. This should create the CSV file somewhere, correct?

Comment: No, when you call the function `extract_url()` it will *return* (not print, nor download) the url to the dataset (the python console automatically "prints" everything that you don't store in a var, but the python exec doesn't). Then you can use a further `requests.get` on that value to download it somewhere. I suggest you study some more Python though, before trying to make things work by copy and paste.